# How to call another file when if condition is met for values in a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame that contains value "0" every now and then. I need to check whether these values are available in another file and if yes, I need it to replace the 0. Its a little hard to explain, so I will use an example.

| ItemCode | Section_A | Section_B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 145 | 10000 | 100 |
| 165 | 15000 | 150 |
| 185 | 0 | 200 |
| 205 | 25000 | 0 |

As you can see, there are occasional 0s. On the side, I have separate files for each column headers. I want to write an R code where if there is a value of 0, then store the itemcode for that row, search the respective column file and see if there is the true value.

```
DF1 <- data.frame(ItemCode=c("145","165","185","205"), 
                  Section_A=c("10000","15000","0","25000"), 
                  Section_B=c("100","150","200","0"))

SectionA_File <- data.frame(ItemCode=c("145", "155","165","185", "195", "205"), 
                            Tag=c("10000","3900", "15000","60000","9999","25000"))

SectionB_File <- data.frame(ItemCode=c("145", "155","165","185"),     
                            Tag=c("100", "125", "150", "200"))
```

For instance in DF1, For Section_A, ItemCode(185), the value is 0. I want to call a command to take the 185 value and search the SectionA_File for it which is "60000". On the other hand, In DF1, Section_B, ItemCode(205) does not exist in SectionB_File, so 0 will be kept. Can anyone help me with this?

Desired Output:

| ItemCode | Section_A | Section_B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 145 | 10000 | 100 |
| 165 | 15000 | 150 |
| 185 | 60000 | 200 |
| 205 | 25000 | 0 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clunky:

```
library(dplyr) # v1.1.0
DF1 %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("Section"), ~ifelse(.==0, NA_character_, .))) %>%
  rows_patch(SectionA_File %>% rename(Section_A = Tag), unmatched = "ignore") %>%
  rows_patch(SectionB_File %>% rename(Section_B = Tag), unmatched = "ignore") %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("Section"), ~ifelse(is.na(.), 0, .)))
```

Or:

```
DF1 %>%
  left_join(SectionA_File, join_by(ItemCode)) %>%
  left_join(SectionB_File, join_by(ItemCode)) %>%
  transmute(
    ItemCode,
    SectionA = pmax(Section_A, Tag.x, na.rm = TRUE),
    SectionB = pmax(Section_B, Tag.y, na.rm = TRUE)
    )
```

Result

```
  ItemCode Section_A Section_B
1      145     10000       100
2      165     15000       150
3      185     60000       200
4      205     25000         0
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

DF1 %>% 
  pivot_longer(-ItemCode, values_to = "Tag") %>% 
  left_join(bind_rows(list(Section_A = SectionA_File, Section_B = SectionB_File), 
                      .id = "name"), by = c("name", "ItemCode")) %>% 
  mutate(Tag = replace_na(if_else(Tag.x == 0, Tag.y, Tag.x), 0)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(c(ItemCode), names_from = name, values_from = Tag)

#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>   ItemCode Section_A Section_B
#>   <chr>    <chr>     <chr>    
#> 1 145      10000     100      
#> 2 165      15000     150      
#> 3 185      60000     200      
#> 4 205      25000     0
```